# Group an array and print its values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

```
$galleries = array (
    '0' => array ('post_id' => 300, 'photo_id' => 1),
    '1' => array ('post_id' => 300, 'photo_id' => 2),
    '2' => array ('post_id' => 300, 'photo_id' => 3),
    '3' => array ('post_id' => 301, 'photo_id' => 4),
    '4' => array ('post_id' => 301, 'photo_id' => 5),
    '5' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 6),
    '6' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 7),
    '7' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 8),
    '8' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 9),
    '9' => array ('post_id' => 303, 'photo_id' => 10),
    '10' => array ('post_id' => 303, 'photo_id' => 11),
    '11' => array ('post_id' => 304, 'photo_id' => 12),
)
```

I want to group `post_id` and print it in HTML or in PHP to something like this:

```
300 = 1,2,3
301 = 4,5
302 = 6,7,8,9
303 = 10,11
304 = 12
```

Comment: What have you tried? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php will be useful

Comment: Is this really in an array or is it in a data base where you could use GROUP BY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$galleries = array (
    '0' => array ('post_id' => 300, 'photo_id' => 1),
    '1' => array ('post_id' => 300, 'photo_id' => 2),
    '2' => array ('post_id' => 300, 'photo_id' => 3),
    '3' => array ('post_id' => 301, 'photo_id' => 4),
    '4' => array ('post_id' => 301, 'photo_id' => 5),
    '5' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 6),
    '6' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 7),
    '7' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 8),
    '8' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 9),
    '9' => array ('post_id' => 303, 'photo_id' => 10),
    '10' => array ('post_id' => 303, 'photo_id' => 11),
    '11' => array ('post_id' => 304, 'photo_id' => 12),
);
// written on the go, untested
$grouped = array();
foreach ($galleries as $gallery) {
    $grouped[$gallery['post_id']][] = $gallery['photo_id'];
}

foreach ($grouped as $key => $values) {
    echo $key . ' = ' . implode(',', $values) . "\n";
}
```

What do you mean "in HTML or in PHP"?

Comment: Thanks Veseliq! That whas exactly what I needed!! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Hi Veseliq! Sorry for bothering you. Can you give a tip of how to serialize each group? I'm trying to save it on a database... I tried: foreach ($grouped as $key => $values) {
    $group = serialize($grouped);
    echo $group . "<br/>";
}

Comment: Why would you serialize it. What do you need that for?

Comment: I found a way already! I just need to save a serialized data of each array on a mysql database. I'm importing a database from Joomla Mosets Tree component to a new Wordpress website. I'm using excel and PHP to convert the data and assign the new IDs for the photos. I did this and it worked as I wanted: 
foreach ($grouped as $key) {
 $str = serialize($key);
 echo $str."<br/>";
}

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php // RAY_temp_mvetter.php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$galleries = array (
    '0' => array ('post_id' => 300, 'photo_id' => 1),
    '1' => array ('post_id' => 300, 'photo_id' => 2),
    '2' => array ('post_id' => 300, 'photo_id' => 3),
    '3' => array ('post_id' => 301, 'photo_id' => 4),
    '4' => array ('post_id' => 301, 'photo_id' => 5),
    '5' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 6),
    '6' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 7),
    '7' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 8),
    '8' => array ('post_id' => 302, 'photo_id' => 9),
    '9' => array ('post_id' => 303, 'photo_id' => 10),
    '10' => array ('post_id' => 303, 'photo_id' => 11),
    '11' => array ('post_id' => 304, 'photo_id' => 12),
)
;
/*
I want o group post_id and print it in HTML or in PHP to something like this:

300 = 1,2,3
301 = 4,5
302 = 6,7,8,9
303 = 10,11
304 = 12
*/

// COLLAPSE THE ARRAY
$old_post_id = FALSE;
foreach ($galleries as $arr)
{
    $out[$arr['post_id']] .= $arr['photo_id'] . ',';
}

// REMOVE THE TRAILING COMMAS
foreach ($out as $key => $str) $out[$key] = rtrim($str, ',');
print_r($out);
```

Comment: Note that I did something that usually makes me itch - I lowered the error_reporting() so I could use undefined indexes as if they were empty data elements.  But in any case it tested out OK and shows how you can index the array elements.  HTH, ~Ray